# Knife tool not working in 2.90.1

Tags: modeling

I have just updated to the latest version of blender and the knife tool has stopped working. Does anyone know a fix for this?

System specs:
Intel i9-9980XE 64 bit
2 Quadro RTX 5000 GPU's
Windows 10 Pro version 1809

Thanks!

Comment: Working fine here but I'm using Windows 10 Pro version 20H2 and AMD Ryzen 7 2700X with Nvidia Geforce RTX 2070 Super GPU.

Comment: Please elaborate on what's not working. Are you using a shortcut or clicking on the tool icon ? Are you in edit mode ?